# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016 - workflow in waiting state: An open execution context was found but did not match organization for current SDK call

Tags: dynamics-crm, workflow

We just recently migrated an organization to Microsoft Dynamics 2016.  Several of the workflows we've triggered are stuck in a waiting state. Under the details section of the workflow instance I see the following:

"An open execution context was found but did not match organization for current SDK call"

Here's the stack trace:

"Unhandled Exception:

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: An open execution context was found but did not match organization for current SDK callDetail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
  <ErrorCode>-2147220970</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
  <Message>An open execution context was found but did not match organization for current SDK call</Message>
  <Timestamp>2016-12-19T04:30:21.1057215Z</Timestamp>
  <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
  <TraceText i:nil="true" />
</OrganizationServiceFault>
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.Retrieve(EntityReference entityReference, ColumnSet columnSet, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType, Boolean checkAdminMode)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InprocessServiceProxy.RetrieveCore(String entityName, Guid id, ColumnSet columnSet)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy.Retrieve(String entityName, Guid id, ColumnSet columnSet)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.WorkflowLoader.LoadWorkflow(Guid workflowActivationId, IOrganizationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Caching.WorkflowActivationCacheLoader.LoadCacheData(Guid key, IOrganizationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Caching.CrmMultiOrgCacheBase`2.CreateEntry(TKey key, IOrganizationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Caching.CrmMultiOrgCache`2.CreateAndAddEntryCallback(String itemkey, TValue value, IOrganizationContext context, Object parameter)
   at Microsoft.Crm.CrmCache`1.AddEntry(String key, TValue value, IOrganizationContext context, AddEntryCallback`1 callback, Object callbackParameter)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Caching.CrmMultiOrgCache`2.CreateAndAddEntryWithLock(TKey key, IOrganizationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Caching.CrmMultiOrgCacheBase`2.LookupEntry(TKey key, IOrganizationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.ActivityHostBase.StartWorkflow(ICommonWorkflowContext context)"
```

Anybody know the cause of this?  How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Do you have custom plugins and/or workflow actiivities? Is your CRM organization operating on a multi tenant deployment?

Comment: We use both custom plugins and workflow activities.  Our CRM organization is operating on a multi tenant deployment.

Comment: In that case it's good to check if your code is thread safe. Keep in mind that both plugin classes and workflow activity classes cannot have class level fields (static or not). I suspect you have a class that is storing an `IOrganizationService` instance in a static field. This instance is sometimes being used in an execution pipeline belonging to another CRM organization.

Comment: Thanks Henk, I've encountered the issue around class level fields before in the past.  This error is occurring on a workflow that isn't calling any custom code activities.

Comment: Still the workflow can trigger a plugin, e.g. by updating a record...

Comment: I'm assuming that class level functions would also not be thread safe either.

Comment: Functions/methods cannot be the problem. Class level fields (static or not) are.